# Cannot destructure property 'urls' of 'pin' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small project, to fetch image from unsplash, even I check many times, I still have one problem in my code, I am running my code, but it is always give this error, but I don't get it. Any idea will be appreciated.

**Mainboard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Pin from './Pin';
function Mainboard(props) {
let { pins } = props; 
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <Container>
            {pins.map((pin, index) => {
                let {urls} = pin;
              return <Pin key={index} urls={urls}/>
            })}   
        </Container>
    </Wrapper>
  )}
 export default Mainboard;
```

**Pin.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

function Pin(props) {
let { urls } = props;
return (
    <Wrapper>
    <Container>
     <img src={urls?.regular} alt="pin"/>
    </Container>
 </Wrapper>
)}
export default Pin;
```

Comment: Can you show the code of where Mainboard is being used?

Comment: Some item in `pins` array is undefined and `let {urls} = pin` will throwing an error. Try with `let { urls } = pin ?? {}`

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346595/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-getnewpins/66346693#66346693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the main issue is destructing from an undefined object (this is only a symptom), but more that you have "holes" in your data, i.e. your array has undefined elements in it.

If there is an `undefined` element in your `pins` array then perhaps you should filter them first before mapping. A quick way is to apply a `Boolean` constructor against the truthy defined values and the falsey undefined values, i.e. `arr.filter(Boolean)`.

```
function Mainboard({ pins }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Container>
        {pins.filter(Boolean).map((pin, index) => {
          const {urls} = pin;
          return <Pin key={index} urls={urls}/>
        })}   
      </Container>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Of course you should try to ensure your data array is properly maintained in the first place so "holes" aren't introduced. If you add how `Mainboard` is rendered, what the props values are that are passed to it we may be better able to help optimize.

Comment: App.js here for Mainboard.js, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346595/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-getnewpins/66346693#66346693